# Behaviours: Should I always return a reference to the behaviour on its methods?

Tags: architecture, oop, behavior, haxe

I'm writing a small game to sharpen my programming skills, and I've chosen to use behaviors (that basically is a class that modifies its parent, to do things like movement, damage and stuff) to avoid duplicating code... maybe...

Whenever I need to modify the properties of a behavior, I need to get it from the "Actor", like this:

```
actor.getBehaviour(BehaviourType).method();
```

It's OK until I need to modify multiple properties, like following:

```
actor.getBehaviour(BehaviourType).method();
actor.getBehaviour(BehaviourType).setFoo(10);
actor.getBehaviour(BehaviourType).setBar("privet", "russian_hello");
```

Wouldn't that be more convenient if I just return a reference to the behavior on every method (every method needed)?:

```
actor.getBehaviour(BehaviourType).method().setFoo(10).setBar("privet", "russian_hello");
```

I apologize for any mistakes or broken logic (including broken grammar).

Thank you very much and have a nice day/afternoon/night/pokemongo/vim>sublime but i use sublime anyways!

Comment: TBH, I think you'll get your answer only when you'll be done with your project.

Comment: I think this is much more a general programming question than anything specific to games.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for here? Your only actual question appears to be "would this be more convenient?" which is pretty subjective in nature. Are you asking *how* you'd make this change, or what the downsides might be? Or are you purely looking for a discussion about the pros and cons of the technique? You might want to ask on [GDNet](http://www.gamedev.net) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do already return a reference to the behaviour with the getBehaviour method. You can store the reference in a variable and work with it. Personally, I wouldn't return the components from the other methods.

Something like the following if a local variable is enough:

```
YourBehaviour behaviour = actor.getBehaviour(BehaviourType);
behaviour.method();
behaviour.setFoo(10);
behaviour.setBar("privet", "russian_hello");
```

I'm not quite sure which language you're using, but it appears that you might benefit from some kind of generics (C#/Java) or templates (C++) to get a reference of the specific behaviour type and call the corresponding methods, so that you won't need to cast it explicitly all the time.